# Do I need a transit visa to travel through Amsterdam to Ukraine?

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, nigerian-citizens

I have a Nigerian passport and a Ukraine visa and will be travelling from Nigeria to Kiev (Ukraine) via Amsterdam. I have a 3-hour stopover for the KLM flight in Amsterdam. I do not have time to get a Schengen visa to go out of the airport. So in this case can I stay inside the terminal for 3 hours without a visa? I can manage only with cabin bag and all the flights are with KLM. I have exactly the same situation during return trip.

Comment: Is it in a single booking?

Comment: Nigeria is not one of the [countries whose citizens need an airport transit visa](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/binaries/netherlandsandyou/documents/publications/2017/01/01/list-of-countries-whose-nationals-need-an-airport-transit-visa-in-the-netherlands-en/List_of_countries_whose_nationals_need_an_airport_transit_visa_in_the%20Netherlands%20(EN).pdf) (pdf).  You therefore need a visa only if your you plan to leave the airport.  You do not plan to leave the airport.  You therefore do not need a visa.

Comment: @Crazydre doesn't matter.

Comment: @crazydre yes is in a single booking.

Comment: @phoog I don't plan of leaving the airport. I can sit and wait till the next connecting flight. Is just 3hours

Comment: @Tony Good, then no visa is needed :)

Comment: @Crazydre as I said, it doesn't matter whether it's on a single booking. KLM has airside check-in facilities at Schiphol, and the traveler has no checked luggage.  Even if there were checked luggage, KLM would be able to check it through.

Comment: @phoog It's very rare these days for bags to be checked through on separate tickets. Is it the case specifically with KLM at Shciphol?

Comment: @Crazydre I have no recent experience with bags being checked through on different tickets; it was probably 20 years ago that this happened to me.    I know specifically about Schiphol that there is an international transfer desk in the sterile area.  If the traveler were to bring checked luggage and were KLM to require the traveler to retrieve it at the baggage claim, then it would be necessary to pass through immigration control.

Comment: @phoog It used to be common back then, but isn't anymore. Plus, as I've mentioned before, at a lot of airports, with separate tickets (even with only hand bags) the staff will treat the transit airport as the destination, because the airline could be forced to fly you back if you're stuck at the transit airport with too little money to get. Not sure about Nigerian airports, but at all European airports where I've asked, this is definitely the case